# How to connect from windows client to centos git server on local netwowk

Tags: centos, windows, git

In Linux CentOS:

```
yum install git
cd /home
mkdir mysite
cd mysite
git init
```

In Windows 10:

```
git clone https://my_server_username:my_server_password@192.168.1.10/home/mysite/mysite.git
```

it returns:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://192.168.1.10/home/mysite/mysite.git/': Failed to connect to 192.168.1.10 port 443 after 1014 ms: Connection refused
```

I can connect using SSH and my firewall is disabled on both OSs.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve what you want: use your Linux box as a git server.

- run a gitd daemon process on the server.
  This can be done using a web server (http/https) front-end or an SSH front-end.
- run without a server/daemon process by configuring your .ssh/authorized_keys on the server like described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/343675).